# PHP include path isn't working on OS X

Tags: php, macos, xampp

So ever since I got my Mac including files with PHP

> Warning: include(Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social/include/core.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social/index.php on line 1

This is my php include:

```
<?php include("Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social/include/core.php") ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you please add your php code, where you include the `..../core.php`?

Comment: `<?php include("Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social/include/core.php") ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot the starting slash `/`, so your code tries to include the file relative to your script.

You can try this include:

```
include("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social/include/core.php")
```

What also can be helpful, is using [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) or the [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function.